# Does a shaman need to know the spell to use it with Fetish Creator?

Tags: savage-worlds, deadlands-reloaded

I'd like to verify my understanding of the Shaman's Fetish Creator edge.

When a fetish is created, can it be created out of any spell available to the player's shaman, or any spell that can be cast by a shaman?  I originally thought the first but upon re-reading I noticed the "Still subject to rank restrictions" which implies that it's not subject to being known by the player.

> Once per game session, the shaman
>       can create a magic talisman and imbue it
>       with arcane energy. The device uses any
>       power available to the shaman (though
>       this is still subject to Rank restrictions).

And just to verify, it's once per session and it doesn't seem to "Expire", meaning you could carry around a backpack full of these things or sell them if you wanted.  They don't seem to be subject to the restriction of "Tying Up" your arcane energy.

This seems fairly on par with the alchemy edge now (Which is limited to powers you know)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part of the Fetish Creator Edge says the following:

> This is a shamanic version of the Gadgeteer Edge.

So any rulings regarding the Gadgeteer Edge also apply to this Edge. The version of Gadgeteer that appears in *Savage Worlds Deluxe* is more thorough and answers your first question about power availability:

> The device […] uses any power available to Weird Scientists in that setting (though this is still subject to Rank restrictions).

Since Fetish Creator is the Shaman version of Gadgeteer, that means that it can be used for any power available to Shamans in *Deadlands Reloaded*, so long as the Shaman is of a high enough Rank. It does not matter whether or not the Shaman already knows the power.

You also asked if it "expires" and can be used in subsequent sessions. The [official ruling](http://peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=245712#245712) from Clint Black of Pinnacle Entertainment Group is as follows:

> Gizmos from the Gadgeteer Edge only last for the game session they are made in. To create more permanent devices would require a different Edge or ability.

The intention is that the Gadgeteer Edge is for impromptu usage of powers that aren't normally known, whereas the Alchemy Edge is intended to be an alternative method of casting.